Adding manifest exogenous variable to SEM leads to error
I am new to SEM, and some help would be very appreciated.
I want to specify a model with one latent endogenous variable, five latent exogenous variables, and a manifest exogenous variable. Something like this:
Factor.A =~ a1 + a2 + a3
Factor.B =~ b1 + b2 + b3 + b4
Factor.C =~ c1 + c2 + c3
Factor.D =~ d1 + d2 + d3
Factor.E =~ e1 + e2 + e3
Factor.F =~ f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 + f6
Factor.F ~ Factor.A + Factor.B + Factor.C + Factor.D + Factor.E + pre_k

Running this code leads to the following error:
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
What am I doing incorrectly?

This question seems more related to coding than to statistics and is more in place at Stack Overflow. I doubt you won't get any helpful answers here, sorry.
